# Prevent saving of emptry strings in database

Tags: teradata

Oracle has a great native feature that prevents the saving of empty strings to the database by converting them to nulls.  Teradata, however, allows empty strings.  I end up having to write helper code in my application to turn empties into DBNull.  Is there a setting (perhaps at the table level) that someone who isn't a DBA can modify to force empty strings to nulls?

Comment: or another option is to use trigger before insert or update.

Comment: In fact this feature is native to Oracle, all other DBMSes do it like Teradata :-) Of course there's a difference between NULL and empty string. There's no way at the table level, but you might use a view with NULLIF(col, '') in it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not leverage value list compression on empty string for the column(s) in question? Furthermore, NULL values will be compressed automatically as well.

```
ALTER TABLE {MyDB}.{MyTable} ADD {Column1} COMPRESS ('');

CREATE TABLE {MyDB}.{MyTable}, NO FALLBACK
({Column0} {DataType} {NULL|NOT NULL}, -- Can't compress PI Column(s)
 {Column1} VARCHAR(255) COMPRESS (''),
 {Column2} CHAR(4) COMPRESS (''),
 {Column3} INTEGER COMPRESS -- Compress NULL values only
)
PRIMARY INDEX({Column0});
```